# iOS - Unable to scroll UITableView after remote content loaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

When I load remote content via a block I update the UITableView by calling reloadData. However, I am unable to scroll on this data. I think this is because I have declared that the number of rows in the table is the length of my NSArray variable that will hold the contents of the list. When this is called though, the list has a count of zero. I would have assumed that by calling reloadData on the tableView that it would have recalculated the list size again.
Perhaps I'm missing a step along the way. 
Thanks
Here is my code

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"MYURL"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
}
-(void) fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError* error;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    self.dataList = json;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SongCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if([self.dataList count] > 0){
        NSDictionary *chartItem = [self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary *song = [chartItem objectForKey:@"song"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [song objectForKey:@"title"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: IS there enough data to cause a scroll. Does the table move at all when you touch it? Could there be another view (with a clear color) in front which is intercepting the touch calls? Nothing seems blatantly obvious from your code as being wrong. Does the table display the data but not allow you to scroll?

Comment: I think there is something going with ivar releasing. How is the `self.datalist` property defined? Random errors = memory errors (often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. 
The cause of the problem was the I had added a pan gesture to the UITableView

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

This seems to interfere with the ability to scroll on a table. Hopefully this will help anyone who comes across this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `json` object (and therefore `self.dataList`) is not nil at the end of the asynchronous call. If it is, then `[self.dataList count]` will return 0.

Also, make sure that you correctly set `self.dataList.dataSource`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No the JSON object is not nil. My dataList object is being populated correctly as the data appears in the table. Its just not scrollable. Thats what leads me to believe that the table view thinks it has zero rows therefore doesnt enable scrolling

Comment: Do you see any rows with data at all in your table?

Comment: Yes, I can see about 10 and a half rows....the rest disappear off screen. The content is being displayed correctly, just not scrollable.

Comment: In this case I'd make sure that your table can accept user input. Check the values of `dataList.userInteractionEnabled` and `dataList.scrollingEnabled`. In addition, you can also check the value of dataList.contentSize, and see if the content height is greater than the table height. That is another necessary condition for scrolling.